# IIS High CPU Load on ApplicationHost.config change

Tags: iis, configuration, load, cpu

I'm developing an C/C++ application (service) that works with IIS 7.5-10.0 (Windows Server 2008 R2 - Windows Server 2016). It can add web applications and bind them with application pools or delete applications and pools on demand. These web applications are used by our customers when they working with our web sites. At this moment we have about 2000-2500 unique web applications and associated app pools in IIS ApplicationHost.config file on each web server (about 2.5 MB).

Every web server serves about a hundred applications and CPU workload are usually between 5 to 15 % and everything works fine until its time to add new app or delete existing. After that CPU workload jumps up to 100% and stays high for several seconds. At this moment everything on a server gets stucked and our customers begin to complain.

We are using Intel Xeon CPUs (up to 10 cores) and SSD RAID, but it not helps us to increase performance in this situation. At these moments CPU queue are about 5 to 10 times of its normal, so even a modern CPU can't cope with it.

As I noticed the reason of this behaviour is that IIS notifies all working instances of web applications (w3wp.exe) after every change (add or remove web app or pool) of its configuration. And each of working w3wp.exe instances do something inside nativerd.dll thread (I guess they re-reads IIS configuration in reaction of global notification) and loads the CPU by 2-5%. But usually there are about a hundred of them on a web server, so the freezing for a several seconds is guaranted because CPU is overloaded by 200-500%.

Need to say that all these published web applications are a third party software, so I have no their source code and I can't change them. I'm just writing a service application.

Is it possible to disable these notifications to w3wp.exe processes?
These processes have nothing to do with the fact that there's one more web application or pool was added. They are isolated and don't affects each other after all.

Can you please advice me something in this situation?

Maybe there's some method of optimizing ApplicationHost.config size or reorganize its structure?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

no responses in that long, probably sorted by now, but for other people reading this try putting in a delay between each write to the app hosts file.